# Navigation between layout inside custom soft keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on creating a custom soft keyboard using [this](https://github.com/amirisback/keyboard) library, and I've successfully creating my own custom keyboard. However, I'm facing difficulty in navigating through the layout I've added inside the keyboard.

What im trying to do is implementing navigation inside custom soft keyboard to show different layout for example an input form & list page.
using this class below i can navigate between BaseKeyboard class but the layout is not showing

```
class KeyboardNavigationHelper {
   companion object {
    fun navigateTo(baseKeyboard: BaseKeyboard<*>, destinationKeyboard: BaseKeyboard<*>) {
        baseKeyboard.parent?.let {
            if (it is ViewGroup) {
                it.removeView(baseKeyboard)
            }
        }

        destinationKeyboard.parent?.let {
            if (it is ViewGroup) {
                it.addView(destinationKeyboard)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any insights and advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!.